# Android processing priority

Tags: java, android

I am using android eclipse for programming.
I will use this basic calculation to fit to what I want to happen.

Here: 
I got two buttons add and minus. if i press add it will obviously call the method add.
But my problem is. if I will keep pressing add button. It will keep adding multiple times and
if I will click 2 buttons at the same time it will also do add and minus. What I want is that
if i click both button at the same time there's priority that add button will execute first
and the minus button will not send data.

```
Add(){
    a = b + c;
}
Minus(){
    a = b - c;
}

public void add(View view){
      Add();    
}

public void subtract(View view){
      Minus();
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate of your requirement as its not clear what you mean?

Comment: 1. priority scheduling threads maybe. 2. if i click add button it will perform add function right?. if i click both button at the same time the add will perform but the minus will be cancelled. It's like if add is still in process the minus button will be cancelled\

Comment: I think there is a conceptual misunderstanding. Actually, both actions happen sequentially, not in parallel. Therefore, @Etun's suggestion won't work. Additionally, it will be hard to detect whether both buttons are pressed because usually they just emit the click event. If you manually try to click both at the same time, you are likely to actually press one of them first, so one event will be emitted before the other.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `button_minus.setClickable(false);` in `Add` method and
`button_add.setClickable(false);` in `Minus` method.  Then enable them back.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
private boolean isAddButtonPressed;

private void setListener(){
    buttonAdd.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                isAddButtonPressed = true;
            else
                isAddButtonPressed = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void add(View view){
   doMath(true);
}

public void subtract(View view){
    if(!isAddButtonPressed)
        doMath(false);
}

// "synchronized" means that this method can ran only one time at a time
private synchronized void doMath(boolean isAdd) {
    if(isAdd) {
        Add();
    } else {
        Minus();
    }
}
```